# setBody on HTTPCallout not working apex to stripe

Tags: apex, rest, stripe

I used some similar code I had done successfully in a trailhead here

```
public class HttpCallout {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String makePostCallout() {

        System.debug('----apex controller---');
        String key = '********************test key**************************';
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + key);

        request.setMethod('POST');

        request.setBody('{"name":"John Steinbeck", "email":"JS@gmail.com"}');

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if(response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('response.getStatusCode()-------'+ response.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('response.getBody()-------'+ response.getBody());
            System.debug('response.getStatus()-------'+ response.getStatus());
        } else {

            System.debug('ELSE-----------'+response.getBody());
        }
        return response.toString();
    }        
}
```

This will create an empty customer in Stripe (blank name and email). name and email are null in the response. What am I doing wrong?

Also, any apex to stripe link to examples would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're having trouble with a third party API, your first stop should be to look at that third party's documentation. [Here's Stripe's API documentation for the customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=curl).

Combine that with [their API Introduction page](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl), and it's easy to see that JSON is not how you send data to them.

It's instead "form-encoded", meaning that you basically do the same thing as if you were to add data to the query string and you put it in the body instead of in the url.

- key=value pairs
- '&' between each pair
- spaces replaced with '+'
- non-alphanumeric characters percent-encoded

so `name=John+Steinbeck&email=JS%40gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks @Derek F. I was looking at the documentation still couldn't get there. Thanks for the clarification.